# Is there a way to find an element in a linked-list by its index from the end of it

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a non-cyclic linked list data structure. Like this:

```
public class LinkLst<T>{
    private Node<T> first;

    public LinkLst(T t){
        first = new Node(t);
    }
}

public class Node<T>{
    private T t;
    private Node<T> next;

    public Node(T t){
        this.t = t;
    }

    public void setNext(Node<T> n){
         this.next = next;
    }
}
```

So we know by default the List contains no cycles. Is there a way to find a n-th element from the end of `LinkLst<T> lst` with only one iteration if `n <= size(lst)` and throw `IndexOutOfBoundException` if `n > size(lst)`.

```
public <T> T fromTheEnd(LinkLst<T> lst, int n){
   //...?
}
```

The only thing I could find is to reverse it and then find the desired element, but it requires 2 iterations. One for reverse and one to find the desired element. Also memory overhead.

Comment: Can you add `previous` pointers to the class? Then it's easy: Start at `first->prev` and iterate over `prev` instead of `next`.

Comment: @twain249 Unfortunately list is single-linked.

Comment: @twain249 Even if it was doubly-linked, `first->prev` would be null, since linked list is non-cyclic.

Comment: Ok do you know the size of can you save it? Then it's the `size - n` from the beginning.

Comment: @twain249 You can see the code. There is no `size` field.

Comment: @Andreas. I can see how it's currently defined. It doesn't mean it has to be defined that way. Asking if adding a couple of simple fields is allowed as those are the most straight forward solutions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
public <T> T fromTheEnd(LinkList<T> ts, int idx) {
    Node<T> follower, leader;
    // We iterate until the leader hits the end of the list. follower follows leader
    // idx steps behind, so when leader.next = [], follower is the desired node.
    follower = leader = ts.first;
    for(int j = 0; j < idx; j++) {
        leader = leader.next;
    }
    // leader is now idx steps ahead
    while(leader.next != null) {
      leader = leader.next;
      follower = follower.next;
    }
    // leader has hit the end (next is null)
    // follower has your data
    return follower.t;
}
```

In essence, this is a single iteration with two "heads."

Example of indexing `2` into `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, from the end.

```
Setup:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 ^ Leader
 ^ Follower

First loop:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 ^ F   ^ L

Second loop round 0:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    ^ F   ^ L

Second loop round 1:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
       ^ F   ^ L

Loop ends: next(leader) = []
deref(follower) = 3
```

You'll probably want to factor out the method `<T> LinkList<T> last(LinkList<T>,  int)` that returns the suffix of the list with the given length, which lets you express `fromTheEnd` as just `last(ts, n).first.t`.

Comment: Like this better as it doesn't require saving n spots rather just 1 extra.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to iterate twice, you'd have to remember `n` values, which requires memory. Whether that's better than iterating twice is for you to decide.

Create an array of size `n`, and add values to array in a cyclic manner as you iterate the list.

When reaching end of list, and at least `n` elements have been iterated, the nth-from-last element is in the *next* position of the cyclic array.

This sacrifices memory for performance.